# Jquery - How to get click event within hidden div?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery and the action Im trying to get is when a person clicks a button I have it slide down a hidden div underneath it and display the hidden div. Inside that div there is a form field with a submit button. How would I go about listening for the event of someone clicking the submit button inside that div? I cant seem to get it to work:

**UPDATE: This seem to work, let me know if this is the proper way:**

```
$('.button.green.table').live('click',function() {

    var dataString = $(this).attr('title');

    $("#formdiv" + dataString).slideToggle("fast", function() {

    //Added, this works
            $(this).find('.button').click(function() {

    alert($('input[name$="notes"]').val());

    return false;

    });

        return false;

    });

});
```

**EDIT SOME HTML:**

```
<button class="button green table" title="1">Add Notes</button>
<div id="formdiv1">Notes<br /><input type="text" name="notes" value="12" />
<button class="button" id="buttontest">GO</button></div>
```

Comment: Try providing some html to help figure out what may be wrong here.

Comment: any reason for using live?, also `alert($(this).(':input').val());` is not correct, could be your problem.

Comment: @Matt The html above is loaded via an ajax call

Comment: @John so you want the sibling to that button. You can do that or give an id to the input box. Also, look into delegate. Not a huge deal, but delegate is a little faster than live and in general just better to use.

Comment: @Matt Thanks. I asked about how to listen to click events from within html content served via an ajax call and was told on stackoverflow to use live. That is why I was using live.

Comment: @John look at my answer, you might find it a little easier than what you have, since it deals with classes and it will only create one instance of each instead of a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd begin by taking the buttons click event out of the forms slideToggle event as it doesn't belong there.

also, are you sure the id's are correct once the page is rendered?  I always use the class selector and never the Id because in asp.net the id's can change.  you don't specify what you are using

**edit**

```
$("#formdiv" + dataString + " .button").click(function(){
  //your code here
});
```

or

```
$("#formdiv" + dataString + " .button").live("click",function(){
  //your code here
});
```

Comment: I updated the code that seems to work. Is that a good solution? If not what would be a better solution?

Comment: again, i'd take the click event out of the slide toggle as it doesn't really belong there.  but other than that it looks ok.  maybe also get rid of the find and just use the selector like ("#formdiv" + dataString + " .button")

Comment: You say remove it out of the slide toggle. Where should it go then? Be its own function? Or outside the slidetoggle but inside the live click of .button.green.table? Appreciate the help, still learning jquery.

Comment: @John outside the slide toggle

Comment: see my edit and yeah place it within the <script> tag as you would a normal JS function but without the function keyword.  just as my edit is.  and move dataString declaration out side the $('.button.green.table').live jQuery event too so the other event has access to it

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nC67m/

Using the selector

`$(':input[name=notes]', $('#formdiv' + dataString)).val()`

I would recommend not doing it the way you are doing it though. I would actually use classes probably with some selection on the parent. This way it's more general and you can have as many as you want without selecting with an id. Simpler code as well.

So you could do something like:

http://jsfiddle.net/nC67m/1/

note delegate works just like live, but better.